# 1 string that are 2 words with no whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm doing a tracking application for my company and I really need your help

I've got some strings that display it wrong

I'll get the postcode/zipcode and the city name and the "function" (for example distrubition basis)
The string I get is something like that (it's swiss and the format is postcode cityname function)

```
place = "5506 MägenwilDistributionsbasis";
```

now postcode is "5506"
cityname is "Mägenwil"
function is "Distributionsbasis"

my question is how can I split the cityname and function (for this example now)?
 
is it possible to do it with regex or an if statement?

Comment: So you know what the function name is going to be before splitting the string?

Comment: You will have to define some rule about how you know what is city and what is function... otherwise you're out of luck

Comment: you must have the Exact city name, or function in order to be able to split the string

Comment: sometimes there are no function name so I get the postcode and cityname but I'm fine with that. The problem is when I actually get the function name and sometimes it shows it like that and sometimes it has a whitespace between the function name and city name

Comment: What programminglanguage are you using?

Comment: Are there any rules to the capitalization of the function name?

Comment: Create seperate strings for each functions, that will be easier.

Comment: I think the only option is to store all the available functions name in array and then check if the string contains one of the functions name

Comment: @MarcvanNieuwenhuijzen Javascript

Comment: @FlorianPeschka the city and function name are always capitalized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string using the following regexp:

```
var myString = "5506 MägenwilDistributionsbasis";
var units = /(\d+ )([A-Z][^A-Z]+)(.+)/g.exec(myString);
```

Check out contents of array `units`: there you see `units[0]` is the whole string, and `units[1], units[2], units[3]` are what you need.

**Note** According to comments I must say, it's just a draft for possible solution to let you understand how to start working on the problem in JS. So when you will test your application with more complicated city names and function names in the "magic string", try to figure out what regexp fits your purposes perfectly, because `([A-Z][^A-Z]+)` definitly will not match all the known city names.

Comment: This also only works because the umlaut `ä` is conveniently in the character class `[^A-Z]`. But that holds true for lots of other letters, e.g. `Ä` ...

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many cities in Switserland that have multiple capital letters and dashes, so it doesnt work. See my answer for a slight modification.

Comment: I've got one more Problem
I've got this string "3030 Bern Hauptsitz Die Post"

3030 is postcode/zipcode
Bern is the city name and
Hauptsitz Die Post is the function

unit1 is 3030, unit2 is Bern Hauptsitz Die and unit 3 Post

is there a possibility only to get the first Uppercase cityname until the next uppercase word comes?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement that in the most primitive way. Something like this:

```
place = "5506 MägenwilDistributionsbasis";
var codeAndNameAndFunction = place.split(" ");
var code = codeAndNameAndFunction[0];
var nameAndFunction = codeAndNameAndFunction[1];
var startOfTheFunction;

for (var i = 1, len = nameAndFunction.length; i < len; i++) {
    myCharacter = nameAndFunction.charCodeAt(i);
    if (myCharacter >= 65 && myCharacter <= 90) {
        startOfTheFunction = i;
        break;
    }
}

var name = nameAndFunction.slice(0, startOfTheFunction);
var functionName = nameAndFunction.slice(startOfTheFunction,nameAndFunction.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight modification of Florian Peschka's answer:

You can split the string using the following regexp:

```
var myString = "5506 Yverdon-les-BainsDistributionsbasis";
var units = /(\d+ )(.+)([A-Z][^A-Z]+)/g.exec(myString);
```

Check out contents of array units: there you see units[0] is the whole string, and units[1], units[2], units[3] are what you need.

**Note** that this will only work if the "function" name is always in the form of Capital Letter followed by Non-capital letters.